# Рандомный ответ из списка в Telegram-боте на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, list, случайные-числа

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при каждой отправке команды бот выдавал случайное значение из списка. Он, конечно, делает это, но вариант меняется лишь при каждом перезапуске команды. Можно ли как-то пофиксить это?

Основная часть кода выглядит так:

```
games_for_one_player = ['Skyrim', 'The Witcher: 3', 'Portal 2', 'Borderlands 2', 'Half-Life 2', 'Destiny 2', 'Limbo', 'Atomic Heart', 'Life is Strange']
random_game_for_one = random.choice(games_for_one_player)
games_for_two_and_more_players = ['Dota 2', 'CS: GO', 'Rust', 'Raft', 'It Takes Two', 'GTA 5', 'Dont Starve Together', 'Overwatch', 'Hearthstone', 'Smite', 'Call of Duty']
random_game_for_friends = random.choice(games_for_two_and_more_players)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def first(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как ты хочешь провести время в игре? Один (/solo) или с друзьями (/with_friends)?')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['solo'])
def one(message):
    text1 = f'Можете поиграть в {random_game_for_one}!\n'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['with_friends'])
def friends(message):
    text2 = f'Можете поиграть в {random_game_for_friends}!\n'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text2)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Я понимаю, что рандом в питоне не совсем рандомный, но хотелось бы знать, как можно пофиксить это, чтобы в дальнейшем владеть данной информацией :)

Comment: Используй функции рандома не глобально, а локально как в коде ответа ниже. Именно из-за глобального объявления функции у тебя возникает подобная ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете выбирать случайную игру каждый раз при получении команды.

```
games_for_one_player = ['Skyrim', 'The Witcher: 3', 'Portal 2', 'Borderlands 2', 'Half-Life 2', 'Destiny 2', 'Limbo', 'Atomic Heart', 'Life is Strange']
games_for_two_and_more_players = ['Dota 2', 'CS: GO', 'Rust', 'Raft', 'It Takes Two', 'GTA 5', 'Dont Starve Together', 'Overwatch', 'Hearthstone', 'Smite', 'Call of Duty']

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def first(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как ты хочешь провести время в игре? Один (/solo) или с друзьями (/with_friends)?')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['solo'])
def one(message):
    random_game_for_one = random.choice(games_for_one_player)
    text1 = f'Можете поиграть в {random_game_for_one}!\n'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['with_friends'])
def friends(message):
    random_game_for_friends = random.choice(games_for_two_and_more_players)
    text2 = f'Можете поиграть в {random_game_for_friends}!\n'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text2)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Заработало! 
Спасиибо Вам большое-пребольшое! :)

Comment: @stigmvtv пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить, как ответ